# Internal SATA HDD Always Hangs The Next Day On Any Write-Access

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, windows-explorer, freeze, sata

I have a 250GB Maxtor 7Y250M0 SATA HDD that worked fine on my Dell XPS400 running Windows XP. Now I use it as second internal HDD for my Lenovo M85 running Windows 7.  The installation went smoothly and I could access the HDD no problem; however, the next day Windows Explorer would hang when I attempt to write to it.  This happens consistently: as long as I restart the PC, writing to the HDD is fine, but it would fail overnight.  This happens even after I completely formatted the HDD.

Does anyone have any idea? What sort of magical things happen overnight that hang the write access to the HDD?

Comment: Any kind of software (antivirus) (or malware or virus) that you have in the first disk. Or missing SATA drivers.

Comment: This honestly sounds like the symptoms of a failing hdd

Comment: Try it with new SATA cable

Comment: @Reichard The SATA drive was installed automatically by Windows 7. I can't find any explicit driver for 64 bit Windows 7. AntiVirun software doesn't do anything special overnight. So that can't be it. But I'll check if there's anything scheduled overnight.  Power Option is a big suspect now I come to think of it.

Comment: @Ramhound A failing HDD should be consistently flaky, no? The HDD functions just fine all day until I come back the next day...

Comment: @NikolaD Thanks for the reminder about the notorious cable problem but I don't think it fits the symptoms here.

Comment: Anything in the Windows Event Viewer logs?  Does it hang on writes only, not reads?  I'd agree that some power state could be an issue . . .

Comment: @ernie Good point. I have not checked event log for a couple of months. System log's warnings have only to deal with network issues. There is one Application log warning that's of interest as it refers to an old shared folder before formatting the HDD: The content source <file:F:/Shared Documents/> cannot be accessed.

Context:  Application, SystemIndex Catalog

Details:
 The object was not found.  (HRESULT : 0x80041201) (0x80041201)

Comment: Looked Task Scheduler. Got 2 errors of "The task image is corrupt or has been tampered with" on Task ValidationTaskDeadline and Task TVSUUpdateTask.  As far as daily tasks, only 2 GoogleUpdateTasks are scheduled every night.

Comment: I'd probably hit it with a smart test tool to make sure its not some problem with the drive itself, maybe hdtune or gsmartcontrol?

Comment: @Journeyman Geek Thanks and I'll try one of these sometime in the future. For now, I doubt the HDD is the problem. The HDD is good for hours upon system reset, but overnight access to it becomes extremely sluggish and always hang the Windows Explorer and I'd have to reboot to return the System and the HDD to normal.

Comment: **>>> WALK-AROUND** OK. I've isolated the problem further and found a walk-around for now.  I set Power Options' `Put the computer to sleep` to **Never** last night.  Lo and behold, this morning the HDD continued to operate normally.  If I look into the Advance Power Settings, the Hard disk category still has the `Turn off hard disk after` setting set to **20 minutes**.  So setting the system to never sleep has nothing to do with turning off the HDD, yet it avert the HDD access problem... THIS IS VERY PUZZLING.  Anyone with any clue please chime in. Thanks!